# RavenDB build 701 : System.InvalidOperationException: There is no index named: dynamic/

Tags: ravendb

I moved to the latest stable build 701 , and I am getting this error.

Note that am moving up from the previous stable build and have not imported the database.

any ideas why?

Comment: You've probably solved this already, but if not, are you sure you didn't make any explicit call to that index? Maybe you had some dynamic index created from some query and then you relied on that index being there and explicitly made queries on that index. And when you upgraded your old dynamic indexes weren't there anymore.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.